Is this Trek Checkpoint SL5 the right size for me?
Before fully committing to this bike, I just wanted to check to make sure it's properly sized for me. I apologize for the bad picture (after taking it I realize my saddle is too high), but my main concern at the moment before getting properly fitted, is making sure the bike is the right size (*this is a 58cm).
I'm 6'0 with a 33-in inseam. Doing some research, most people with my measurements opt for a 56, and I keep seeing people say to err on the smaller side because you can always make a smaller bike bigger, but not necessarily the other way around. I especially see a lot of people with my measurements sizing down because this bike is quite long.




Hi, welcome to bicycles.  What makes you think this bike is too large?  (Actually, it would be useful to say what size it is.)  It may just be your position on the bike but if anything it looks like the reach is a bit short.

Hello @DavidW, thank you for the welcome and feedback.
My concern mostly comes from my own ignorance. This is the first time I've spent this kind of money on a bike and after doing a bit of digging around I have found that most people with my measurements go for 56 (this is 58). Also, I'm on the very low end of Trek's measurements for this bike and I often see people recommend erring on the side of going down in size (because you can always make a smaller bike larger). Lastly, when I ride I can see the front hub poking out toward me, which I have heard suggests the bike is too long.

When you write Most people with my measurements go for 56 (this is 58), do you mean in general or specifically for this Trek? Size measurement are not homogeneous across models (sometimes even within a brand). Asking because according to Trek's sizing guide, your measurements match better the 58 than the 56 (for comparison, for a Diverge, you would need a 56).

Better take a photo in tighter clothing, with the hands on the hoods and the saddle lowered slightly. It's hard to judge body position like this. The upright back would indicate that the bike isn't too large.

Hello @Renaud, I mean specifically for this bike. When I search for something like "Trek Checkpoint 6'0 33 inseam" and look up discussion boards, it seems like a vast majority of people go with the 56. Also with general searching I have found many people say that Trek tends to recommend sizing large and the general consensus seems to be to opt for a smaller size. Furthermore, consensus seems to be to err on he smaller side because you can always make a bike that is slightly small a bit larger. I fully admit that this type of research is far from scientific! I'm very new to this.

Hello @Erlkoenig, I have added a couple more pictures. Unfortunately I don't have much in the way of tight fitting clothes.

I don't think the bike is too big. The general position looks good. You can still fine-tune the handlebar and saddle position as needed. But you're going to need tighter clothes soon anyways

Thanks @Erlkoenig and I hope you're right! I was about 100 lbs heavier this time last year, and still plenty to go! Cycling bug hit me hard, but my current bike I've been using is clearly not right for me. Thanks again for the help.

Your foot position may be a bit forward of where people usually put their feet. Old practice was mount the cleats about under the ball of the foot; newer practice is a bit aft of that.

Personally, I would rather trust Trek than online comments. With 6'0 height and and 33" inseam, you are just in the middle of their height recommendation and on the low end of their inseam recommendation, and outside their height range for a 56, so it's not what I would consider to be "between two sizes". I don't see any "red flag" with the updated pictures in terms of position, but pictures online are not the most scientific way either ;-). If you want to be sure, the best is probably a professional "bike fit" (there's also a consensus that it's one of the best investments).

Unless a frame is grossly mis-sized, it's difficult to tell from a single photo on the internet.
Bike stores are supposed to size you. That is, someone will sit with you and perform some basic adjustments. They'll set the saddle at roughly the correct height and fore-aft position. From there, they should look at you on the bike.
In particular, we would want to see you with your hands on the brake hoods, not on the bar tops where they are in the photo. If your saddle is in the correct position, your arms should be slightly bent in the hoods. If you instinctively prefer the tops of the handlebars (your current position), that can indicate that the reach is too long. Now, the distance from you to the brake hoods can be changed by fitting a longer or shorter stem. Sometimes, bike stores are willing to swap the stock stem with something they have on hand if you know what length stem you need. They can also raise the bars vertically if needed. But if you have a short stem and you need the bars closer, that would be bad.
Paying extra for a bike fit is an option that people should consider. The retail assistants working in bike shops will size people using an algorithm provided by the bike manufacturer plus some basic knowledge. Bike fitters have more advanced knowledge. Coincidentally, Cycling Weekly recently published an article featuring a new cyclist who went for a bike fit before buying.
Of course, most people don't do this, and most of us buy a bike and then modify our fit after the fact using our own perceptions and information we hear from others - some of which might be wrong in general or wrong for you.
In any case, at minimum, I'd approach the store in person and ask to be sized to the bike. Trek does accept returns of bikes (and other things) within 30 days in like new condition, so that can be your last resort. If you take a test ride and you feel like you are stretching too far forward, that's not good - to some extent your body can adapt to a more aggressive position, but you shouldn't be doing that with your very first bike unless you're very athletic and you know you want to get into racing. Visually, I concur your saddle is too high, and I think most experienced riders would agree. Move it to the correct height and that should slightly reduce the reach to the handlebars. Do that and then see if the handlebars are at the right distance.

Thank you for the help. While you were writing that I updated my original post to include a couple more pictures.
